# Storing IAP in UserDefaults so the user doesn't need to restore the purchase every time a "purchasable" button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect

Background: My app provides a number of prompts from a group of arrays. The 'packs' determine which prompts can be toggled on. You start with a default pack and then can purchase the three additional packs (packA, packB, and packC) for a non-consumable IAP.

My goal is to have the user pay for it once, and then be able to access the packs whenever he/she likes; however, once the sandbox user makes the IAP, a popup says *"You've already purchased this. Would you like to get it again for free?"*. I obviously don't want this popping up every time the user selects a pack. Is there anyway to make the purchase a permanent use and not need to constantly restore the purchase?

Below is my current code (anonymized and reduced to only the essential components):

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore
import StoreKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {


    //MAIN SETUP SECTION XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

    let productID = "com.domain.appName.additionalPackages" 
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    //I'm just putting "Various" here as a placeholder for my multiple buttons
    @IBOutlet weak var (Various): UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self) 

        //I don’t know if this actually does anything        
        func cleanUp() {
            for transaction in SKPaymentQueue.default().transactions {
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            }
        }

    }




    //PACK SELECTION SECTION XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

    var packA = 2
    var packB = 2
    var packC = 2
    var packsUnlocked = false

    @IBAction func selectPackA(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if packsUnlocked == false {
            print("It's locked, ‘Pack A’ not enabled")
        } else if packCounterA % 2 == 0 {
            if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() { // In App Purchase
            let paymentRequest = SKMutablePayment()
            paymentRequest.productIdentifier = productID
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(paymentRequest)
            print("Initiating Transaction")
        } else {
            print("No Purchased")
        }
        promptProvider.includeA.toggle()
            packCounterA += 1
        } else {
            promptProvider.includeA.toggle()
            packCounterA += 1
        }
    }

    @IBAction func selectPackB(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if packsUnlocked == false {
            print("It's locked, ‘Pack B’ not enabled")
        } else if packCounterB % 2 == 0 {
            if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() { // In App Purchase
            let paymentRequest = SKMutablePayment()
            paymentRequest.productIdentifier = productID
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(paymentRequest)
            print("Initiating Transaction")
        } else {
            print("No Purchased")
        }
            promptProvider.includeB.toggle()
            packCounterB += 1
        } else {
            promptProvider.includeB.toggle()
            packCounterB += 1
        }
    }

    @IBAction func selectPackC(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if packsUnlocked == false {
            print("It's locked, ‘Pack C' not enabled")
        } else if packCounterC % 2 == 0 {
            if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() { // In App Purchase
            let paymentRequest = SKMutablePayment()
            paymentRequest.productIdentifier = productID
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(paymentRequest)
            print("Initiating Transaction")
        } else {
            print("No Purchased")
        }
            promptProvider.includeC.toggle()
            packCounterC += 1
        } else {
            promptProvider.includeC.toggle()
            packCounterC += 1
        }
    }




    //TRANSACTION FINALIZATION SECTION XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) { 
        for transaction in transactions {
            guard
                transaction.transactionState != .purchasing,
                transaction.transactionState != .deferred
            else {
                //Optionally provide user feedback for pending or processing transactions
                continue
            }

            if transaction.transactionState == .purchased || transaction.transactionState == .restored {
                print("Transaction Successful")
                packsUnlocked = true
                //new
                defaults.set(true, forKey: "Purchase Pack") 
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize() 
            } else if transaction.transactionState == .failed {
                print("Transaction Failed with error")
            }

            //Transaction can now be safely finished
            queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
        }
    }



}
```

This is my first app but I think the issue is with the saving of the purchase to `UserDefaults`. I'm very new to this so any help is extremely appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Where do you store pack purchase status?  The keychain is common. The user should only have to attempt to purchase again if they are on a new device or have erased their device

Comment: @Paulw11 that may be my problem I have no idea how to store the purchase status for each individual if that isn't already done in the above code. I've searched online for help on that but can't find anything. Any ideas where this code is documented/exemplified?

Comment: It is up to you.  I am sure there are IAP tutorials on sites like Ray Wendedlich.  Storing a value in the keychain is common,   You can use a framework like KeychainSwift to make it easier.

Comment: You can store the [State](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransactionstate) (purchased, restored) with related `productIdentifier` using persistent storage on device . You should not use UserDefaults because it can be manipulated (such as someone can replace it as purchased even though it is not), you can store it on Keychain as suggested above. You can use, `paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:)` delegate.

Comment: @omerfarukozturk I'm actually fine with the limitations of userDefaults since I'm really just trying to get this product to the market by deadline and then can improve it after it hits the market. The link you sent me is very helpful but I'm having issues differentiating it's method of using UserDefaults from my method. It seems that I'd doing everything the documentation tells me to do... Any advice on [persisting my transaction] (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/persisting_a_purchase)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Basics

After the purchase was done you can access the receipt at `Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL`. You can use that receipt and validate it against the App Store, to prevent someone from using a fake receipt.

The validation response will tell you that the receipt it legit and has not been refunded. It also tells you that the subscription is still active and when it will expire.

You can do all this on the client but it would be best practice to store the receipt on the server so you can validate it on your end instead of leaving it up to the client for potential manipulation.

> Do not call the App Store server verifyReceipt endpoint from
>   your app. You can't build a trusted connection between a user’s device
>   and the App Store directly, because you don’t control either end of
>   that connection, which makes it susceptible to a man-in-the-middle
>   attack.

You can find more infos including code examples in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/validating_receipts_with_the_app_store). In addition you can set up [hooks](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/enabling_server-to-server_notifications) so that your sever will actively be notified when the subscription status changes.

### PoC

If you don't care about the aforementioned security implications and just want to do a proof of concept, you can do this in the app and check whether the user has already made a purchase:

1. Get the receipt from `Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL?.path`
2. Validate the receipt with the App Store server as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/validating_receipts_with_the_app_store); note that the sandbox and production App Stores have different URLs for validation
3. Get `product_id` and `expires_date` from the validation response to know which product has been purchased and whether it's already expired

Remember that if the user uninstalls and reinstalls the app, the receipt is not stored on the device. The user has then to restore the purchase where the app downloads the receipt from the App Store server. That is what happens when you press the "Restore Purchase" button that you are probably familiar with from other apps. Restoring is simply done with the `SKReceiptRefreshRequest`.

Comment: Thanks @Manuel - I'm actually fine with the security limitations of using UserDefaults for this one - so my main issue is really just making my purchase persistent. Do I need to do more receipt stuff with my existing code or do you think there's just an issue with it somewhere preventing the purchase to persist?

Comment: I've added a guideline for a simple proof of concept to the answer.